# Is there a standard method of module for calling a function from within a ConfigParser file?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm trying to set up my configurations so that I can have functions that I call from the config that then parse into a result.

I would expect the config would be something like this

```
[sectionOne]
option1 = split('item1|item2|item3',0,0,'|')
```

And when loaded by ConfigParser would result in it calling the defined `split()` function.

If I have to, I'll build out the logic for handling this, but I'm trying to see if anyone knows of an existing module that would handle this translation.

Comment: I basically need a set of string manipulation functions that can be exposed in the configuration file. If you have a better suggestion on implementing that I'm definitely willing to listen to suggestions.

Comment: I apologize for my snarkiness, but the point of it was that _this is a bad idea_ and you should back up a bit and find a different way to accomplish your _larger_ goal.  For instance, you could arrange that if a value starts with `[` `"` or `{` it gets run through [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.loads) or [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not shure i understood your question, but if i did, you can define a dictionary of functions

```
funcs = {'split':split}
```

two options,

```
option1func = 'split'
option1args = ('item1|item2|item3',0,0,'|')
```

and then execute

```
option1value = funcs[option1func](*option2args)
```

in your code. You sure can just `eval(option1)`, but this is not a very good practice.